# Scrapy and submitting a javascript form

Tags: javascript, python, forms, scrapy

I'm learning scrapy and I've run into a snag attempting to submit a form that is controlled by javascript.

I've tried experimenting with a number of things found here on Stack Overflow including Selenium but having no luck (for a number of reasons).

The page I need to scrape is...
http://agmarknet.nic.in/

...and do a commodities search. When I inspect elements it appears to have a form "m", with a filed "cmm" needing a commodity value.

```
<form name="m" method="post">
(...)
<input type="text" name="cmm" onchange="return validateName(document.m.cmm.value);" size="13">
(...)
<input type="button" value="Go" name="Go3" style="color: #000080; font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold" onclick="search1();"></td>
```

Any advice gratefully accepted!

UPDATE:
I've tried this with selenium, but it doesn't find or populate the field. I also wouldn't mind being able to do this without popping up a firefox window...

```
    CrawlSpider.__init__(self)
    self.verificationErrors = []

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://agmarknet.nic.in/")
    time.sleep(4)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("cmm")
    elem.send_keys("banana")
    time.sleep(5)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    driver.close()
```

UPDATE:

I've also tried various iterations of the following, but with no luck. When I submit the search from the web page, fiddler2 tells me it is post'ing the string "cmm=banana&mkt=&search="...but when I use the code below, fiddler tells me nothing is being posted...

```
class Agmarknet(Spider):
    name = "agmarknet"
    start_urls = ["http://agmarknet.nic.in/SearchCmmMkt.asp"]


    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(
                    response,
                   #formname = "cmm1", 
                    formdata={
                    'method':'post',
                    'cmm': 'banana', 
                    'mkt': '', 
                    'search':''},
                    callback=self.after_search)]

    def after_search(self):
        print response.body
```

OUTPUT FROM ABOVE:

```
{'download_timeout': 180, 'download_latency': 13.44700002670288, 'proxy': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'download_slot': 'agmarknet.nic.in'}
Spider error processing <GET http://agmarknet.nic.in/SearchCmmMkt.asp>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 1201, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 382, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "Z:\WindowsDocuments\eclipseworkspaces\BioCom\manoliagro-agmarknetscraper\src\bin\agmarknetscraper\spiders\agmarknet.py", line 34, in parse
    callback=self.after_search)]
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.0-py2.7.egg\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 36, in from_response
    form = _get_form(response, formname, formnumber, formxpath)
  File "Z:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.2\python-2.7.6\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.0-py2.7.egg\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 59, in _get_form
    raise ValueError("No <form> element found in %s" % response)
exceptions.ValueError: No <form> element found in <200 http://agmarknet.nic.in/SearchCmmMkt.asp>
SpiderRun done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the page consists of two frames, a short glance at the source reveals their names 'contents' and 'main'. So your script above nearly does the job, merely missing a single line pointing to the right frame called 'main' with driver.switch_to_frame('main'). Also the form does not react to ENTER-key, we indeed have to select the button and press it :-).

This code is working:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://agmarknet.nic.in/")
time.sleep(4)

driver.switch_to_frame('main')
textinput = driver.find_element_by_name('cmm')
textinput.send_keys("banana")
time.sleep(1)

button = driver.find_element_by_name("Go3")
button.click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Barrios. Thank you! Brilliant! If I may, I have a follow-up question... Is it possible to grab the data from the post-search page without having the browser actually pop up (silent in the background)

Comment: TNX for the compliment, wasn't so hard to figure out :-). You can indeed use a so called "headless" browser like PhantomJS with selenium, which has no display. I don't know how well this browser works. If you are on a linux machine you can also put Firefox on a virtual framebuffer in the X-window-system with [xvfbwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xvfbwrapper/0.1.3)

Comment: Hey...so I ran into another bug with this same problem. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to post it here, so I started a new thread...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203080/selenium-will-not-click-button

Answer (score 1):

with or without javascript, in the end, the call will **always** be translated to some http call, use firebug to track down that call type (get/post), fields and values it is translated to and add those to your scrapy Request.

Answer (score 0):

What will make your life easier especially with javascript is [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/). It is a firefox-plugin able to record what you click & type in firefox and afterwards showing you the code for certain elements you need to put in your python-script. Was very useful for me, not only with forms. :-)

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll look into the IDE. I did use Fiddler2 and I think its a post request along the lines of name=cmm&mkt=&search= but I wasn't able to get a post request to go out through the scrapy request. Can you direct me towards some code snippets?

Comment: So, I tried selenium IDE with Firefox and it actually recorded nothing. All it showed was an OpenAndWait and nothing more, ever though I completed a search and got results.