# Cannot Run Scrapy in WinPython

Tags: python, scrapy

I am attempting to run a scrapy web crawler off WinPython installed in a USB stick, so that the crawler can be used on any windows computer without the need for python to be installed on the desktop itself.

I've installed WinPython (32 bit, 2.7.6.4) and used pip to install all the dependent packages, except pyOpenSSL--I downloaded the binary for that. After that, I installed scrapy. However, whenever I type scrapy into the command prompt, an error message would appear:

```
'scrapy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I read up on this error message and a potential cause was the environment variable path, which I have set to:

```
D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6;D:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6\Scripts
```

I am still getting the same error message, and would appreciate any help on this issue. I believe running scrapy on WinPython should be possible, as I have seen [other Scrapy posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173959/scrapy-and-submitting-a-javascript-form) with error messages containing WinPython directories.

Comment: Check if you have a scrapy.bat somewhere in the path from the installation; this fubared last time I tried to get scrapy working under Windows, and I had to create it myself.

Comment: @fiskfisk thanks for the suggestion. Did you have the same exact problem, and creating scrapy.bat solved the issue? Unfortunately, I deleted WinPython and attempted a different approach using Portable Python instead. I believe the problem was either with my scrapy installation or with WinPython's path. I will post my workaround using Portable Python, and perhaps someone else who has done it with WinPython could explain how they got around this problem- if they encountered it.

Answer (score 0):

To run scrapy off a USB drive, I eventually chose to use Portable Python instead of WinPython; it achieves the same purpose. In order to do this:

1. Install [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) on your USB drive
2. In the command prompt, move to the App\Scripts folder created by Portable Python's installation and use *easy_install* to install the following packages: pywin32, zope.interface, lxml and pip. For example, typing *easy_install pywin32* on the command prompt would install pywin32.
3. Download [pyOpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl) and install it into the App folder
4. Go to control panel >  system > advanced system settings > environment variables. Edit the Path variable by adding the folder in which python.exe resides, as well as the scripts folder. In my case, I added *D:\PPython27\App;D:\PPython27\App\Scripts*.
5. In the command prompt, install scrapy by typing *pip install scrapy*.
6. Type *scrapy* in the command prompt to see if it works. Mine did, although I had an error message that asked me to install a package called *service_identity*- which i did.

After that, I was able to run scrapy right off my USB drive, on a Windows computer that had no Python installed.